# Redirect from old site on Wordpress to Codeigniter. Domain remain same

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm preparing for migration from WordPress to site written via Codeigniter. I use htaccess very seldom, and never redirection.

My site is working now and clients visit my site. And I cannot just upload new site. 
So I tried to practise with one page for redirection to another created for testing. I tried with encoded and decoded URL but without success; however, as written in the manual, it should be a simple:

```
Redirect [status] URL-path URL
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

Redirect 301 /?wpsc-product=подвеска-сова-медь-duplicate http://domain.com/?page_id=851
```

Also, Apache has `RedirectMatch` and `RewriteRule [301]` and they are loading server, so I prefer to use simple redirects (I have CPU load limitation on my hosting). 
I have about 500 links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` OR `RedirectMatch` directive from `mod_alias` cannot match query string. You must use `mod_rewrite` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} wpsc-product=подвеска-сова-медь-duplicate [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://domain.com/?page_id=851 [L,R=301,B]
```

Make sure to keep this rules on top of your `.htaccess`.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Thanks it works! For others - this part подвеска-сова-медь-duplicate must be encoded as "%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C-duplicate"

Comment: Yes because of those special unicode characters. Glad it worked out.